# Change paths in TeXworks after updating to TeXlive '19

Tags: texworks, texlive-2019

I installed TeX Live 2019, without installing TeXworks a second time, because I already have it on my system.

I ran `pdflatex sample2e` and I got

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX)
```

So the installation went ok, as the TeX Live version is the current one.

How do I change the paths in TeXworks? [image: screenshot of Preferences] I assume I have to change the paths outlined in red, as they're the ones which are pointing to the 2018 directory. Could someone clarify?

Comment: This is NOT the correct answer however it gives the confidence to proceed with such ~~ It should be safe in the editor window to **first add +** the new 2019 paths at the **top of the list** make a few tests including exit and re-enter to see they stick. Then use **minus -** on the older 2018 entries. If all is well within the editor then a permanent setting WILL need to be made within the system PATH environment for command line use. you can tell that is correct when the two following commands agree showing exactly ONE IDENTICAL 2019 location `where /r c:\ pdflatex` and `where $path:pdflatex`

Comment: Thank you, @KJO. I tested the new configuration and in the log files I get `(TeX Live 2019/W32TeX)`, meaning adding the 2019 paths worked. The two commands gave me two locations, simply 2018 and 2019. How do I do change this?

Comment: I was able to change the system PATH environment. I also have one identical location for `pdflatex`. Thank you.

Comment: the path order is important with 2019 first then updates should work well through the year. 2018 folder is for fall back (if you have issues that need older version) at that time you would need to "promote" 2018 to be in advance of 2019 on path so that it is used by default. However it is "frozen" so not good to try and update it (bit risky for a multi- years installation, but is possible if critical)